# ios UILabel implement dynamic font size change by UILabel size change

Tags: ios, size, font-size, autoresize

I am trying to implement a function that can change uilabel font size, I can zoom uilabel size(is uilabel.size) , then automatic change the uilabel's font size, the example app is InstaText!

Comment: Something like: `[label setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0]];`?

Comment: I'm Sorry, I know how to set font size, But this is not I want, I want to set fontsize, and the fontsize change with the UILabel size to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Your desired font" size:newSize];
```

or you could do it even easier:

By looking here [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) - set property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`

Comment: I want to implement the action is , When I change the UILabel size then the UILabel fontsize change also.

Comment: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth will do that for you